# Simple bulk delete using EntityFramework.Extended throws syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.1 with MySQL 5.6.24 and I want to bulk delete a large set of records.
I am using [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) to improve performance.

However my first, very simple update query already fails:

```
DbContext.Tickets.Where(t => t.EventID == targetEvent.EventID).Delete();
```

This throws an AggregateException in mscolib, the inner Exception is a MySQLException:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[youreal_TicketPlatform].[Tickets]
FROM [youreal_TicketPlatform].[Tickets] AS j' at line 1]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +501
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +444
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +136
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +1254
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +2626
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   EntityFramework.Batch.<InternalDelete>d__0`1.MoveNext() +1350
```

Has anyone experienced this same error? What is the easiest way to see the actual query being performed? Adding a listener on DbContext.Database.Log doesn't show the query.

Basically I want to bulk remove large sets of data without having to retrieve them first.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue and had found the solution. Just change the default BatchRunner of the Locator from SqlServerBatchRunner to MySqlBatchRunner and it will work with MySQL.

```
EntityFramework.Locator.Current.Register<EntityFramework.Batch.IBatchRunner>(
            () => new EntityFramework.Batch.MySqlBatchRunner());
```

The related code in repository:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Locator.cs

The related issue:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/163

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's because you are using mysql. None of the Bulk tools for EF I know works with mysql. And if you look in source/Database for Extended it only contains SqlServer and SqlCompact.

You can write the Sql yourself and execute that through Entityframework.

Comment: I will definitely consider moving to SQL after this, it seems that MySQL isn't supported enough for business applications...